# How to type in the file directory with backslashes?

Tags: java, file, backslash

I'm trying to draw an image using Graphics2D in Java, but the path cannot be read because `Illegal escape character in string literal`

I am using this line of code:

```
g2.drawImage("C:\Users\User\Pictures\Untitled", playerX, playerY);
```

However, due to the backslashes in the path the path returns an error. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why? Use forward slashes. Java will fix them for you.

Answer (score 1):

Escape `\` with `\`

```
g2.drawImage("C:\\Users\\User\\Pictures\\Untitled", playerX, playerY);
```

Comment: Ultimately that is not going to help - `Graphics2D` has no such method. Create an `Image` with `ImageIO.read` and make that the first argument. The path to `read` can be `"C:/Users/User/Pictures/Untitled"` (though an odd name for an image file)